# Is it possible to reset a DataFrame index by name, instead of level?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to remove an index by name? I am removing and adding lots of indexes in multiple places throughout and I can see it getting quite confusing if I have to keep track of each level at all times.

I am creating a MultiIndex like so:

```
df = cass_df.groupby(['hash', 'campaign_id'])[['accepted', 'rejected', 'positive_impressions', 'negative_impressions', 'revenue']].sum()
```

Currently I am using this code to remove the first index:

```
df = df.reset_index(level=0)
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
df = df.reset_index(level='hash')
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can also add `inplace=True`. You can also remove double `[]` in aggaregate `groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,2,3],
                   'B':[1,1,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  2  1  7  1  5  7
1  2  1  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

df = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C','D','E'].sum()
print (df)
      C  D  E
A B          
2 1  15  4  8
3 6   9  5  6

df.reset_index(level='A', inplace=True)
print (df)
   A   C  D  E
B             
1  2  15  4  8
6  3   9  5  6
```